# Replacing ALL HREF URL attributes with ALT tag and Placeholder Text

Tags: html, href, alt

I need to find an automated way to update href URLs in a HTML file with the corresponding image alt text the anchor tag is wrapping while also including leading and closing RPL text.

Start:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="ALT_TEXT"></a>
End:
<a href="${clickthrough('ALT_TEXT')}"><img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="ALT_TEXT"></a>
```

Breaking down the new URL:

- First Variable: `${clickthrough('<br>`
- Second Variable: `ALT_TEXT<br>`
- Third Variable: `')}`

Anyone know where I should start in designing a solution for this problem? What coding language might handle this?

Comment: Depends on the requirements. Do you want to do this before the HTML file is served to the clients? After? Are you worried about whether the user who is viewing the HTML file (presumably in a browser) has scripting turned off? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The language that you are looking for is JavaScript.

Here is a working example that does what you mentioned. (and here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dordasal/pen/Zdwqba) with the same example)

```js
const anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll('a');
[...anchorElements].forEach((anchor) => {
  const altText = anchor.querySelector('img').alt;
  anchor.href = "${clickthrough('" + altText + "')}";
})
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://place-hold.it/300x100" alt="text1"></a>
<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://place-hold.it/300x100" alt="text2"></a>
<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://place-hold.it/300x100" alt="text3"></a>
```